# The Google Maps API server rejected your request. This IP, Site or mobile application is not authroised to use this API key

Tags: api, google-maps, mobile-safari

I have implemented the Google maps iframe embed api to my website, the map API is working correctly on desktop web browsers as well as Google Chrome for mobile.

However when i attempt to view the page of my site with the API on in mobile safari on  iphone i get an error saying;

"The Google Maps API server rejected your request. This IP, Site or mobile application is not authroised to use this API key".

I Have enabled Google Map API for IOS on the google developer console  and the issue still hasnt gone away. As i said the API works fine on other mobile browsers.

Does any one have any suggestions how to fix this?

Thanks, Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you create a new [Client ID](https://developers.google.com/console/help/#generatingoauth2)?

Handheld devices require "Installed Application" Client ID, not "Web Application. "